# Two scripts: One changing directory other not?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, script

I have two scripts. One is :

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $1 = 1 ]; then 
   dir=mydir-1.6_
else
    dir=mydir
fi
cd ~/code/${dir}$2
echo $(pwd)
```

The above script changes directories even though there are several posts that say that since a script is run in a sub-shell it should have no effect on the executing shell.

Now I have another script:

```
#!/bin/bash
dir=/WORK/temp/$1
mkdir -p $dir
cd $dir
wget http://somurl.com/archive.zip
unzip archive.zip
```

The above script unzips the file in the expected directory but leaves the calling shell in the same directory. What is the difference when cd is called in both scripts?

Comment: The first does not change the running shell's directory for me. It *prints* the path to ~/code/mydirsomething, but then after exiting I'm left back in my original directory. How are you testing it?

Comment: Can you provide a demostration of you running those scripts and the directory changing as a result?

Comment: Here is a demo:
`salilsurendran@salilsurendran-ThinkPad-P50:~$ myscript 1 4
/home/salilsurendran/code/mydir-1.6_4
salilsurendran@salilsurendran-ThinkPad-P50:~/code/mydir-1.6_4$ pwd
/home/salilsurendran/code/mydir-1.6_4
salilsurendran@salilsurendran-ThinkPad-P50:~/code/mydir$ myscript 2 3
/home/salilsurendran/code/mydir3
salilsurendran@salilsurendran-ThinkPad-P50:~/code/mydir3$ pwd
/home/salilsurendran/code/mydir3
salilsurendran@salilsurendran-ThinkPad-P50:~/code/mydir3$`

Comment: Please don't add information in the comments. [Edit] your question and include the extra information there instead. Comments are hard to read, easy to miss and can be deleted without warning. That said, your demo doesn't show that the parent shell changed directory. That;s the `pwd` output from the subshell running the script.

Answer (score 0):

If I  understand what your problem is, you could try executing the second script from the first, passing in expected directory. Like this.

script 1

```
#!/bin/bash
TEST="1234"
echo "$TEST"
bash 2.sh "$TEST"
```

script 2

```
#!/bin/bash
TEST="$1"
echo "$TEST"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first script does not change the directory. I don't know what makes you think it does, but `cd` inside an *executed* script will *never* affect the parent shell. That's just the way it works.

The only way it could change the directory of the parent shell is if you source it instead of executing it. I have saved your first script as `foo.sh` and run it from my `$HOME`:

```
$ pwd
/home/terdon
$ foo.sh 1 
/home/terdon/code/mydir-1.6_
$ pwd
/home/terdon
```

As you can see, the directory is changed inside the script, but the parent shell's PWD remains unchanged. Now, if you source it, it works as you seem to expect:

```
$ . ~/scripts/foo.sh
bash: [: =: unary operator expected
/home/terdon/code/mydir
$ pwd
/home/terdon/code/mydir
```

So, if you want your script to change the directory of its parent shell, you need to source it not execute it. However, if that's what you're trying to do, you want to write a function, not a script:

```
changeDir(){
    targetDir="mydir"
    if [ "$1" = "1" ]; then
       targetDir="mydir-1.6_"
    fi
    \cd "$targetDir"
}
```

Add the above to your `~/.bashrc` and use that instead of a script. Functions always affect the shell that's running them so it will change your directory as you want it to.

Note that I am using `\cd` instead of `cd`. This is in case your `cd` [is aliased to something](https://askubuntu.com/a/525242/85695). Also note that I have changed your script a little to avoid the `bash: [: =: unary operator expected` you were getting with your original approach. In shell scripts, it is [essential](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/22222) to always quote your variables. In this case, when `$1` was empty, the script was attempting to run:

```
$ if [ = 1 ]; then  targetDir="mydir-1.6_"; fi
bash: [: =: unary operator expected
```

Which, of course , gives an error since there's nothing to compare. By quoting `$1` you are comparing the empty string and that will work as expected.